# spring security LDAP get additional fields

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am using Spring Security with LDAP (Active directory), I am able to authenticate user and  create my own user detail object by extending LdapUserDetailsMapper.
By default I am getting certain fields and groups and DN.
But I would like to get additional fields, like email, contact number, which are available in Active Directory.

So how to get those information ?

My configuration

```
 @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("hmie.co.in", "ldap://1.1.1.1:389/");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper);
        return provider;
    }
```

Custom user detail mapping

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsContextMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

   @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<?    extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        LdapUserDetailsImpl ldapUserDetailsImpl = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);     
        MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails();
        myUserDetails.setAccountNonExpired(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isAccountNonExpired());
        myUserDetails.setAccountNonLocked(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isAccountNonLocked());
        myUserDetails.setCredentialsNonExpired(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isCredentialsNonExpired());
        myUserDetails.setEnabled(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isEnabled());
        myUserDetails.setUsername(ldapUserDetailsImpl.getUsername());
        myUserDetails.setAuthorities(ldapUserDetailsImpl.getAuthorities());
        String dn = ldapUserDetailsImpl.getDn();
        int beginIndex = dn.indexOf("cn=") + 3;
        int endIndex = dn.indexOf(",");
        myUserDetails.setEmployeeName(dn.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));
        beginIndex = dn.indexOf("ou=") + 3;
        endIndex = dn.indexOf(",", beginIndex);
        myUserDetails.setDepartment(dn.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));   
        return myUserDetails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the complete LDAP Directory attributes and values i did like this. But here i am using inteface `org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper` instead of class `org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsMapper`.

```
         ldapTemplate.search("o=XXXXX", new EqualsFilter("uid", userName).encode(),
              new AttributesMapper() {

                     @Override
                     public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attr) throws NamingException {
                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          NamingEnumeration<String> namingEnumeration = attr.getIDs();
                          while (namingEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                               String attributeName= (String) namingEnumeration.nextElement();
                               System.out.println(attributeName+" = "+attr.get(attributeName));
                          }
                          return null;
                     }
           });
```

In the above piece of code `attr.getIDs()` returns the Active directory attributes like CN,DN,SN and mail. `attr.get(attribute)` returns the value of attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `mapUserFromContext` is *so* close! The key detail is that the `ctx` object passed in to the method already contains the additional Active Directory attributes for the principal. The attribute values are accessible using method `ctx.getStringAttribute("attribute-name")`. For example, you would access the surname attribute of the principal with `ctx.getStringAttribute("sn")`. To get the user's email and contact number, you would only need to access the appropriate attributes. In my company's Active Directory, those attributes are *mail* and *phone*, respectively. The attributes might be named differently in your system.